# How can the question about explaining SE to a partner be narrowed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, reopen-request, too-broad

[How do you explain, to your partner, that Stack Exchange is important to you?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/how-do-you-explain-to-your-partner-that-stack-exchange-is-important-to-you)

This question, my question, was put on hold for being too-broad. How can I narrow it further?

I'd prefer not to narrow it down to a question that's only going to be useful for me personally. I suppose narrowing it down till it's only useful for me isn't the worst thing, but that seems somewhat less ideal for the usual Stack Exchange format...

The question looks on topic to me, it's a practical problem that I actually face, and I think it can be answered in its current state, but I'm open to improving it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

> My partner occasionally gets really frustrated hearing me talk about, seeing me on, or any real mention of Stack Exchange.

I think you should narrow it down to a problem that you need to solve **with** your partner. Also make clear what your goal is, i. e.

1. Do you want to talk about SE with your partner and get them to listen?
2. Is your partner against you using SE at all?

In comments you only noted that SE doesn't take away too much time you could else spend together. But to revisit the quote, I identify three problems

1. hearing me talk
2. seeing me on
3. any real mention

Now how to tackle the problem greatly depends on your goal:

If it's goal 2, then problems 1 and 3 are rather intrapersonal problems and you should just stop talking about SE to them, if they don't want to hear about it.
Problem 2 is rather something suitable as your partner would seemingly try to cross boundaries here.

In case of goal 1, you are trying to cross your partner's boundaries, so the most fitting answer would be a frame challenge.

Comment: The question was "Is there a polite way to explain Stack Exchange to a significant other in a way that they'll be a little more inclined to accept that it's something that's important to you?" So the goal is closer to 1. Sort of a "Hey this is important to me, would you mind accepting that, or at least stop viewing it as trivial and bashing it?"

Comment: Was that unclear in the OP? I suppose I could edit to clarify.

Comment: @apaul It certanly wouldn't hurt if you clarified it. Also, the three reasons your partner becomes frustrated add to the confusion: There's a huge difference between them being frustrated about you talking about SE 24/7 and you spending all day with them but using your spare "free time" to browse SE and then being met by your partner's frustration after they glanced at your screen.

Comment: I've edited the question.